# How to grab data (titles, thumbnails and custom field) from multiple posts in a specific category to populate a map?

Tags: php, wordpress, dictionary

Basically, I have like 15K posts which I use them for directory purposes. I currently use a map plugin called '5 sec gmap' to show their locations in single posts. I customized that plugin to pull the posts' physical address from a custom-field called $wpcf-address to show.

But, I want create a map for main categories (say dining venues) to show all dining related posts' addresses on the map. So user can see whats close to them and click on to see the whole post(directory).

Comment: You may use [tax_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) to filter out posts from a (or some) given category(ies). Show us how you're querying your posts so we may come up with a full answer.

Comment: Sori i am a newbie, how can I show it? copy/paste php of the template that calls the category view?

Answer (score 0):

```
$category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
$cat_id = $category->cat_ID;
```

This will grab the category for the current page

```
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <!-- WordPress has found matching posts -->
        <div style="display: none;">
            <?php $i = 1; ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'latlng', true) !== '' ) : ?>
                    <div id="item<?php echo $i; ?>">
                        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php $i++; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var locations = [
                <?php  $i = 1; while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'latlng', true) !== '' ) : ?>
                        {
                            latlng : new google.maps.LatLng<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'latlng', true); ?>, 
                            info : document.getElementById('item<?php echo $i; ?>')
                    },
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
            ];
        </script>
        <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>

    <?php else : ?>
        <!-- No matching posts, show an error -->
        <h1>Error 404 &mdash; Page not found.</h1>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

This is an example of using the google api and wordpress loop. You will need to use a custom field for the latlng coordinates for the map. For each post or whatever etc..

```
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var pinkmarker = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/wp-content/themes/mapdemo/pink_Marker.png', new google.maps.Size(20, 34) );
        var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/wp-content/themes/mapdemo/shadow.png', new google.maps.Size(37, 34) );

        function initialize() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
                zoom: 12, 
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.898748, -77.037684), 
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
            });

            for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: locations[i].latlng,
                    icon: pinkmarker,
                    shadow: shadow,
                    map: map
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                  return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(locations[i].info);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                  }
                })(marker, i));
            }

        }
```

Here will be the javascript needed for the map.

If this is unclear to you I would recommend reading the google api documentation and the wordpress documentation too.

Comment: I use WP and google maps. but when i put something like that in the category template, then it shows the same thing in all categories.

Comment: Updated the answer that should grab the category ID for the current page and then you can use that in the loop.

Comment: Thanks. Though how do i put everything together like calling the map, address section inside the posts etc?

Comment: I updated it with new information, hopefully this puts you in the correct direction